# Webapp only per ssl canoncial way

Tags: http, ssl, web-applications, centos, packaging

I just installed owncloud (7.0.10-1) from the EPEL (6) repository to a CentOS 6 server. Given that this rpm contains some "best practices" I want to minimize the changes to the config files that come with the rpm.

The app does work out of the box.

However, the app is available via http, but I prefer https only access. Is there some simple switch to turn off http access or do I have to do it manually? Is there any suggested canonical way to force ssl at all? The wikipages do not seem to mention this at all.